# Making forward search behave (a bit) like backward search

Tags: isearch

When I do reverse incremental search, the cursor is placed at the beginning of a match for my search, and stays there as I type further characters that match. With forward search, on the other hand, the cursor moves forward as I continue to type matching letters. Is there a way to do a forward search that behaves like backward search in this respect? (To place the cursor at the beginning of a match, I first do a forward search, then do a reverse search. I'd like to avoid this, if possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the this in my init taken from the emacswiki to solve this:

```
(defun my-goto-match-beginning ()
  (when (and isearch-forward isearch-other-end)
    (goto-char isearch-other-end)))

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook 'my-goto-match-beginning)
```

If you leave the search, the point will jump to the beginning automatically.

Comment: Thanks. (Can't upvote yet.) Found that Emacs wiki page here, for others who may be interested: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementalSearch